# Magento 2 I Want to add Dropdown Quantity Box In Minicart

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, mini-cart

I am trying to replace Dropdown instead of text box at Quantity at Minicart.

I tried following code  but didn't get success ( i am trying direct in Magento Vendor folder for testing purpose).

> Magento_Checkout\template\minicart\item\default.html

Remove input text box and put the select tag.

```
<select data-bind="options: qtyOptions,attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                            class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
                    </select>
```

I have added js code in minicart.js

> Magento_Checkout\js\view\minicart.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';

  return Component.extend({

        qtyOptions: ko.observableArray([]),

        initialize: function () {

            for(var i =0; i<= 10; i++){
                this.qtyOptions().push(i);
            }


        }

    });
});
```

I have put the bold text code in js file.

Can any one Help to correct the code ?

I got following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below file path to make Dropdown Quantity Box In Minicart.

> Magento_Checkout\template\minicart\item\default.html

```
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>                        
                            <select data-bind="attr: {
                               id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                               'data-cart-item': item_id,
                               'data-item-qty': qty,
                               'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                               },
                               value: qty,
                               options: $parent.qtyOptions"
                               class="item-qty cart-item-qty" style="width:50px">
                            </select>

                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

> Magento_Checkout\js\view\customqty.js

```
define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent'
],function(ko, $, Component){
    return Component.extend({
        qtyOptions: ko.observableArray([]),
        initialize: function(){
            this._super();
            for(var i =0; i<= 10; i++){
                this.qtyOptions.push(i);
            }
            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

> Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/customqty</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Let me know if any query.

Hope it help!

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how to chagne in checkout/cart page? thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please update in the template file as shown in the image